# How to read a vector from the user input in R and use it for further processing [R]

Tags: r

I want to ask the user to enter a list of values in integers.
User can enter a single value or a bunch of multiple values like 1 2 3 (spcae or comma seperated)
Then use the data entered for further computation.

I am using the following code

```
EXP <- as.integer(readline("enter the experiment numbers (You can include multiple number of experiments with space seperate) \n"))
```

Here with or without integer, whatever values I store inside EXP, I cant use them in further programming. Like below

```
gg2 <- subset((aggregate(cbind(var)~En+Mn+hours,a, FUN=mean)),(aggregate(cbind(var)~En+Mn+hours,a, FUN=mean))$En == c(EXP))
```

The above command fails for condition $En == c(EXP), Because the values entered through readline doesnt work.

How do I do?

2) The above question is regarding the integers.
The same solution doesn't work in case of characters as input. just like below

```
 prompt1 <- "enter the variable_name \n"
     var <- as.character((readline(prompt1))[[1]])
```

Here if I enter Ph for the prompt then var will store like "Ph", this value I cant use inside the command line

```
gg2 <- subset((aggregate(cbind(var)~En+Mn+hours,a, FUN=mean)),(aggregate(cbind(var)~En+Mn+hours,a, FUN=mean))$En == c(EXP))
```

It will throw error like,  variable lengths differ (found for 'En')
but if I replace var with the actual value like Ph, then it will work fine.

The dataset is uploaded here... [Dataset](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B31lFEKMpy2jVlNla2dka2lwTG8/edit)
    a <- dataset imported into

```
Consider names(a) = c("Ei","Mi","hours","Nphy","Cphy","CHLphy","Nhet","Chet","Ndet","Cdet","DON","DOC","DIN","DIC","AT","dCCHO","TEPC","Ncocco","Ccocco","CHLcocco","PICcocco","par","Temp","Sal","co2atm","u10","dicfl","co2ppm","co2mol","pH")
```

I am doing this

```
v1 <- quote(var1 <- as.numeric(readline('Enter a number from 1 to 15: ')))
eval(v1)
v2 <- quote(var2 <- as.numeric(readline('Enter a number from 1 to 15: ')))
eval(v2)


variable1 <- as.name(names(a[var1]))
variable2 <- as.name(names(a[var2]))
gg4 <- subset((aggregate(cbind(variable1,variable2)~Ei+Mi+hours,a, FUN=mean)))
```

Reading the user input and then using the user input into the command to aggregate the required data. The above command is using the variable1 and variable2 and so its not working and its throwing error.
If I replace variable1 and variable2 with actual column names like Nphy, Cphy then everything is working fine.

```
like this gg4 <- subset((aggregate(cbind(Nphy,Cphy)~Ei+Mi+hours,a, FUN=mean)))
```

So all I want to know how do we make the user input work inside the command lines?

Comment: Make an object with the aggregate call. Then perhaps the error message will make some sense. Failing that,  then POST SOME DATA.

Comment: I hope you have read my answer. Did it help? If not, can you please provide some feedback and clarify that second part?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first part should be:

```
prompt <- "enter the experiment numbers (space-separated list) \n"
EXP <- as.integer(strsplit(readline(prompt), " ")[[1]])
```

The second part is more obscure (can you explain what your data looks like and what you want to do?) but maybe you are looking for something like this:

```
sub.a <- subset(a, En %in% EXP)
aggregate(var~En+Mn+hours, sub.a, FUN=mean)
```

I don't see the link with `ggplot2`. If none, please delete any mention of it.

Comment: The first part of your answer itself solved my problem. Thanks.             and just a curious question, does explicit handling of subset and then aggregate increases the performance ? compared to combining both in a single call? (considering a huge dataset)

Comment: The above solution works well n good in case of integers. But the same doesnt work in case of characters. I have added a few lines in the main question please take a look, and if you know then please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: No, I'm not sure. It is hard to tell without a reproducible example. One thing for sure is you should not use `==` but `%in%` like I suggested. `==` will only work as expected if `length(EXP)` is `1`.

Comment: I have added the dataset and further more details please look into it, and if you know the solution then please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

You can try `scan()`. Here is an example:

```
> x <- scan()
1: 4

2: 6

3: 10

4: 11

5:

Read 4 items 

> x
[1] 4 6 10 11
```